# Create a flask app to return list of dictionary from xlsx file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a dataframe as shown below, which is in xlsx format

```
  Date           in_days  t_factor
  2020-02-01        1         5
  2020-02-06        6        14
  2020-02-09        9        14
  2020-02-03        3        11
  2020-02-11       11        14
```

I would like to create a flask app to read this data from its location and convert it back to list of dictionary.

I am first time in flask

I tried below code in jupyter notebook to return list of dictionary

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')

def get_function_model_data(caliberation_df):
    df = caliberation_df.copy()
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:
                            dt.datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
    df.rename(columns={'in_days':'InDays'}, inplace=True)
    df = df [['Date', 'InDays']]
    return list(df.T.to_dict().values())
```

I would like to create a flask app to read the excel from its location and return the list of dictionary of selected column.

I tried below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_function_model_data():
    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:
                            dt.datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
    df.rename(columns={'in_days':'InDays'}, inplace=True)
    df = df [['Date', 'InDays']]
    return list(df.T.to_dict().values())
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already for the flask part? Like the routes you have added? If yes, is there any errors on that side etc. ?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj very new in flask, I did not tried anything. I just thought how return an xlsx file as list of dictionary. For my learning purpose.

Comment: Ok, so it is very simple. Just go over this quickstart: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#quickstart . You can just call your `get_function_model_data` function from the `hello_world` function.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj Can you please add your solution. I am also trying with the help of  above link

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj added my try

Comment: Ok, add `@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])` before the `def get_function_model_data` line. Then run flask and check if your method hits by doing a request to that URI